# matrix is not diagonazible if algebraic multiplicity = number of rows of matrix except for diagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Is it possible to say for real matrices, that if the algebraic multiplicity is equal to the number of rows of a matrix, that the matrix is never diagonazible?

But this should only be valid for **non-diagonal** matrices.

Example:

$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$

$\lambda_1=\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 1$

algebraic multiplicity = 3

but geometric multiplicity will never be 3, because $rank(A-\lambda E)$ is at least 1:

$geometric~multiplicity= 3-rank(A-\lambda E)< 3$

Comment: In this *very particular, special case*, yes: if an  $\;n\times n\;$ matrix has one unique eigenvalue, then it is diagonalizable iff it is **already** in diagonal form.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can also prove it as follows.

Suppose that $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalue $\lambda$ having algebraic multiplicity $n$. Then there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} A P = \lambda I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. But then
$$A = P \lambda I P^{-1} = \lambda P P^{-1} = \lambda I. $$
Therefore $A$ itself is diagonal.